# I'm doing a program where i can send emails with php but only @gmail and @ymail can recieve my message except @yahoo.com

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = $email;
    $email_subject = "Confirmation of your Registration";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    // create email headers

    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe it's a spam filter thing? If you're going to be sending lots of email, I'd take a look at a third-party sending API (where you build the email and send through their servers), which take care to get your email delivered without being stopped by spam. I've used [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) in the past and enjoyed it (free tier available).

Comment: Any free alternatives?

Comment: @binoculars Mandrill is free for the first 2,000 emails you send. I'm not aware of any totally free, limitless alternatives, because you're paying for their service and knowledge of sending lots and lots of email (Mandrill [came out of MailChimp](http://www.mandrill.com/about/), which sends [over 600 million emails a day](http://mailchimp.com/about/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please, check the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

You are using the correct php function, however, since this depends on the service provider, it is likely they have either not altered the PHP installation, or customized in a way that they can accept incomplete results.

Check the notes in the documentations for the following:

> If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.

And

> When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.

Finally, the [RFC 2047](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html). and [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) must be obeyed

Answer (score 3):

As per Jake B's comment - I'd not try doing this from your own server.

Find a smarthost (ask your hosting provider about it) or use a 3rd party web API.

If you're insistent on doing it yourself - check your SPF records (google is your friend here).